# Doctrine creates oneToMany for oneToOne relationships

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, relational-database

Why does this Doctrine command

`php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle yml`

create `oneToOne` entries for **identifying relationships** and `oneToMany` entries for **non identifying** relationships if both are oneToOne?

For this relationship:

[image]

This entry is set

```
/Entities/Client
manyToOne:
    photo:
        targetEntity: ClientPhoto
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            photo:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

And for this one

[image]

This relation is set

```
/Entities/​PrivilegePerRole​
oneToOne:
    roleCode:
        targetEntity: Role
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            role_code:
                referencedColumnName: code
        orphanRemoval: false
```

Comment: Maybe because of lack of some unique index.

Comment: @Alex what do you mean? In the first example, id is a PK for the client_photo table and is the one being referenced

Comment: I meant that Doctrine generates entities (and their relations) basing on the db structure. My point is maybe there is no some foreign key which can tell doctrine what kind of relationship it is.

Comment: Yes I understood your answer but in both cases the table has a PK which is unique. Must be some other reason

Comment: PK is not a foreign key. FK point to another table but PK points to the current.